# Python: Create Functions with a Loop

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

How would I make a loop that creates multiple functions?
I need to create multiple functions, with variables for the colX in the example below.

In other words, how would I create a loop to simply the following...

```
def game_col1(self):
    self.player = self.player + 1
    if self.player %2 == 0:
        self.window.col1_playera()
    else:
        self.window.col1_playerb()
    print(self.player)
def game_col2(self):
    self.player = self.player + 1
    if self.player %2 == 0:
        self.window.col2_playera()
    else:
        self.window.col2_playerb()
    print(self.player)
def game_col3(self):
    self.player = self.player + 1
    if self.player %2 == 0:
        self.window.col3_playera()
    else:
        self.window.col3_playerb()
    print(self.player)
def game_col4(self):
    self.player = self.player + 1
    if self.player %2 == 0:
        self.window.col4_playera()
    else:
        self.window.col4_playerb()
    print(self.player)
def game_col5(self):
    self.player = self.player + 1
    if self.player %2 == 0:
        self.window.col5_playera()
    else:
        self.window.col5_playerb()
    print(self.player)
def game_col6(self):
    self.player = self.player + 1
    if self.player %2 == 0:
        self.window.col6_playera()
    else:
        self.window.col6_playerb()
    print(self.player)
def game_col7(self):
    self.player = self.player + 1
    if self.player %2 == 0:
        self.window.col7_playera()
    else:
        self.window.col7_playerb()
    print(self.player)
```

Comment: Please have a look at sections 4.2 ("`for` Statements") and 4.7 ("More on Defining Functions") in the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html). It would probably be useful to look over the table of contents and read any sections you're not familiar with.

Comment: Why not just make a single `game_col` function that takes the number as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

Without delving into the reasoning behind why you have written your code the way you have, I'm going to give you exactly what you've asked for, but be warned: it's ugly. Also, I'm assuming those functions `game_col[1-7]` are members of a class based on the `self` parameter.

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        def game_col(s, i):
            s.player = s.player + 1
            if s.player % 2 == 0:
                eval('s.window.col%d_playera()' % i)
            else:
                eval('s.window.col%d_playerb()' % i)
            print(s.player)
        for i in range(8)[1:]:
            setattr(self, 'game_col%d' % i, lambda: game_col(self, i))
```

If you now declare a game object like so:

```
game = Game()
```

You can use the functions that you desire, like so:

```
game.game_col1()
game.game_col2()
...
game.game_col7()
```

Answer (score 0):

This, while not dynamically achieving what you're asking, will generate the code you desire:

```py
for x in range(0, 99):
    print """def game_col{0}(self): 
    self.player = self.player + 1 
    if self.player %2 == 0: 
        self.window.col{1}_playera() 
    else: 
        self.window.col{2}_playerb() 
    print(self.player) \n""".format(x, x, x)
```